# Execute SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries with single OleDbCommand type

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface where the user provides a SQL query and my server executes it.

I'm using [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which expects you to use `ExecuteReader()`, `ExecuteNonQuery()` or `ExecuteScalar`, depending on whether the query returns multiple rows, manipulates the database or retrieves a single value.

Is there a way to use any of above for all types of query?

Comment: I don't see why `ExecuteReader` couldn't be used for all.  It's just overly cumbersome when you don't really need to setup for, and receive, a row set.  Because at some point you will want >1 rows, you'd have to make that your default choice, I think.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: Well, the problem is that in my GUI user should be the one to type in the query. Since I do not know what will user type ( SELECT, UPDATE etc ) I need "neutral" solution, that is why I asked the question.

Comment: mmmm, allowing users to type in sql, just sounds like a terrible Idea. One way could be to look at the query they want to execute, if it has select, then use `ExecuteReader` code.

Comment: You are setting yourself up for a massive SQL injection headache, as well.  Executing unknown SQLs against your database seems like a bad idea.  What if I enter 'DELETE FROM tbl` for each table?  How do you mean to sanitize the queries?  If you are already inspecting them, then you should be able to tell what sort of query it is and execute it properly.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: This is a small demonstration app. I am looking for a job and simply can't land any long term one. I figured if I demonstrate what I know in a small app that my chances will be higher.

Comment: Understood.  Still, I urge you to reconsider the direction of your demo, then.  Soldiering on with a bad concept is only going to suggest poor decision-making.  The first step to a good app is good design and planning.  Your interviewer won't see your brilliant code, she'll see your poor choice of design.

Comment: Why are you using OleDb?  What kind of database are you querying?

Comment: Also, if you're creating a demo app to use in trying to get a job, creating a demo app that demonstrates the absolute worst practices is counterproductive.  Hiding these would be a better idea.

Comment: @Will: I will use MS Access. I just want the smallest example that illustrates basic stuff, I was not planning to send "full-blown-production-software". I mean really, who will go through lengthy code anyway? I believe that small app that demonstrates usual stuff (simple queries, basic work with controls, some threading and interoperability, **no memory leaks, good coding principles**) would suffice. I will even comment the code to point out my approach, so it doesn't turn out like "this is the best I can do, hire me based on this".

Comment: Nope.  Nope and nope.  If someone came to me (over 10 years developer, have hired many others) with an application that ran raw queries against an MS Access database I'd thank them for their time and laugh my ass off at them after they left. Hey! I have an idea--take my advice.  I've been around the block a bunch and have TONS of it.  Here's what you should do--Ditch Access for Sql Compact, only ask the user for PARTS of a query, not all of it, and use SqlParameters to compose your final query.  Best practice, up on technology, looks good.  Or, you could keep wasting your time. Your life.

Comment: *Ditch Access for Sql Compact, only ask the user for PARTS of a query, not all of it, and use SqlParameters to compose your final query.* I am interested to take your advice, but would need more details. Perhaps we could meet at chat when you have spare time? I would leave you a comment (or you could tell me when to meet) so we can briefly discuss about this. *I'd thank them for their time and laugh my ass off at them after they left.* Jesus, how wrong my approach is! Thank you for "opening my eyes".

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty wrong.  Chat, meh. I'd suggest the following: 1) Grab CLR Via C#, skip the first two chapters, and read. Once completed, read the first two chapters 2) Here's ADO: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163799.aspx 3) I'm borderline on Sql CE... it may be a bridge too far, as if you don't set it up right it may work on your dev machine and not on someone else's.  The other common alternative is Sqlite.  Here's a good series on getting started with it http://www.caveworks.net/Sqlite_Part1 You can start on #1 while you work on 2 and 3.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general of those is `ExecuteReader`.

`ExecuteScalar` just reads the first value in the result set (the first column of the first row). So translating that to `ExecuteReader` is trivial - it already uses `ExecuteReader` internally :)

`ExecuteNonQuery` probably doesn't open a reader, but you can still simulate the same behaviour with `ExecuteReader` - the `DbDataReader.RecordsAffected` property gives you the exact same value. The overhead of having a reader is negligible, especially in the context of a GUI application.

Distinguishing between the output you want is easy in the simplest cases:

- `ExecuteNonQuery` would have no rows at all. So `DbDataReader.HasRows` is false (and `DbDataReader.Read` returns false) - that means you know you only want to return `DbDataReader.RecordsAffected`
- `ExecuteScalar` would usually be used when you have a single row and a single column. You can use `FieldCount` for the columns, rows are trickier (you'll need to read the first row to find out if there's any rows remaining).
- `ExecuteReader` is trivial.

But the key point is that each of those can be used for any query. The important part isn't what the query is doing, it's what your application wants to do with the results. You can always call `ExecuteNonQuery` on a query that selects real data - but that's kind of defeating the purpose. If you do care about those distinctions, just make the user pick whether he wants the affected record count, the first value or the whole result set.

So don't think about what kind of query you're running, that's not important. You can use `ExecuteReader` for a `delete` query, and you can use `ExecuteNonQuery` for a query that returns results. Think about what you want to do with the *results* of the query.

Comment: *Think about what you want to do with the results of the query.* I am building small demonstration app that I wish to send along with my CV when I search for a job. I have treeview that presents tables and their columns in a database, textbox where user enters query, and a listview that should be filled with the result. I just had to handle UPDATE/INSERT/etc types of query. I thought to keep it simple and simply display `MessageBox.Show("Success");` since `catch` will handle errors. That is all, I hope it is clear now. BTW, so far `ExecuteReader` works, based on my tests. 10x 4 answering.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Yup, go ahead with `ExecuteReader`, it's going to work just fine. If you have rows, show them in the list view (or better, a grid), if you don't, you can just show the affected record count.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is No, there is no way you can use the three of them on the same time

`ExecuteReader` : This member is overloaded. For complete information about this member, including syntax, usage, and examples, click a name in the overload list [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx)

`ExecuteNonQuery` : Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

`ExecuteScalar` : Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

as you can see, each one of them has its own usage and no way to combine them all

there is a work around you can make, try using `enum` with the three values and let the user pass the value, and from your side you can make `switch case` that will check the `enum` value and fire the proper function

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. *there is a work around you can make...* Yes, something similar came to my mind as well, but I really do not want to redesign the GUI...

Answer (score 0):

You could analyse the text of the query, and depending on that, your code could pick which Execute method to use.

That would be better than having the user choose something on the GUI.